# Is there a way to build C++ custom qualifiers?

Tags: c++, compile-time, qualifiers

Is there any way to implement a custom type qualifier (similar to const)? I would like to only allow function calls to functions that are of the right qualification, within functions with the same qualification.

Let's say I would have:

```
void allowedFunction();
void disallowedFunction();

//Only allowed to call allowed functions.
void foo()
{
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(); //Cause compile time error
}

//Is allowed to call any function it wants.
void bar()
{
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(); //No error
}
```

The reason I would like to do this is because I want to make sure that functions called on a specific thread only call realtime-safe functions. Since many applications require hard realtime-safe threads, having some way to detect locks at compile-time would guarantee us that many hard to detect runtime errors cannot happen.

Comment: To add new keywords to the language, no there is no chance (unless you can persuade the Committee).  You may be able to use macros.

Comment: I think you may be interrested in this: [Metaclasses: Thoughts on generative C++](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/)

Comment: Maybe you could just put realtime-safe function declaration in specific header files?

Comment: Is [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KPAy02Xi11GFsR4P) what you are looking for? An accessor class can easily solve the problem probably.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can put the functions in a class and make the allowed ones friends of the class like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
    static void f(){}
    friend void foo(); // f() is only allowed for foo
};

void foo() // allowed
{
    X::f();
}

void bar() // disallowed
{
    //X::f();  // compile-time error
}

int main()
{

}
```

You can probably write some crazy macro that does this transparently for every function you'd like to allow/disallow.

Comment: Friending functions doesn't however guarantee me that no disallowed functions are called. In this way we can only disallow specific functions, not disallow all functions and then allow several. I need to be absolutely sure that no locks are taken.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe For finer control you'd need one function per class I guess... That's where a macro comes handier. Nice question though!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on skypjack's comment: Yes, *if* you're okay with annotating every *disallowed* function, so that non-annotated functions are allowed by default. This is called the **Passkey Idiom.** [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cfKo5GsEz):

```
// Any object of type TakesLocks serves as a passkey
// for functions that take mutex locks
//
class TakesLocks {
  friend int main();
  explicit TakesLocks() {} // private constructor
};

void allowedFunction();
void disallowedFunction(TakesLocks);

//Only allowed to call allowed functions.
void foo() {
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(TakesLocks()); // error, can't call private ctor
}

//Is allowed to call any function it wants.
void bar(TakesLocks tl) {
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(tl); // No error
}

int main() {
  foo();
  bar(TakesLocks()); // OK, main is a friend of TakesLocks
}
```

This is useful if you have a "closed" blacklist of `disallowedFunction`s, such that you can enumerate them all, and you control their signatures. But in real life, we'd also want e.g. `TakesLocks` to be required in order to call `printf`, and `strftime`, and so on — there's no way for us to enforce that. So `TakesLocks` is basically the worst example I could have chosen. :)

---

For another approach, much closer to what you originally asked, that has had great success in academia but never shipped in any mainstream compiler as far as I know, see Jeffrey Scott Foster's [Cqual](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eaiken/publications/theses/foster.pdf).

---

EDIT: Just recently I learned that Clang supports the reverse approach via the `enforce_tcb` attribute! "TCB" stands for "Trusted Compute Base," implying that anything *inside* the TCB must never call anything *outside* the TCB. Compile with `-Werror=tcb-enforcement`: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GbhPPPxYe). Use this approach if you're okay with limiting enforcement to Clang and if you're okay with annotating every *allowed* function, so that non-annotated functions are disallowed by default. (This is likely too restrictive, because it means e.g. you can't call `puts` or `sin(long double)` or `std::copy` from an annotated function. Vice versa, Clang quietly whitelists a handful of library functions, like `memcpy`, `sin(double)`, and `std::move`, into every TCB; which might *also* be problematic, depending on your use-case.)

```
// A function inside the TakesNoLocks TCB must not call
// any function outside that TCB.
//
[[clang::enforce_tcb("TakesNoLocks")]] void allowedFunction();
void disallowedFunction();

//Only allowed to call allowed functions.
[[clang::enforce_tcb("TakesNoLocks")]] void foo() {
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(); // error, can't call outside the TCB
}

//Is allowed to call any function it wants.
void bar() {
    allowedFunction();
    disallowedFunction(); // No error
}

int main() {
  foo();
  bar(); // OK, main is outside the TCB itself
}
```